# I changed my domain name and REST API stopped working

Tags: migration

I am building a word-press website, and I have changed my domain name from `websiteold.com` to `websitenew.com`.

The domain transfer was done by the web server host.

However, I am not able to use the rest API since I changed to the new domain name. This is the error I am getting from postman.

```json
{
    "status": "error",
    "error": "UNAUTHORIZED",
    "error_description": "Sorry, you are not allowed to access REST API."
}
```

I have generated a new API key using the application passwords plugin, however whether I use the generated API key or a random/false API key, I get the same response.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening. It might have to do with configurations being associated with old domain name. Please advise what to do.

Comment: did your domain also do the database URL migration? Or did you do that?

Comment: that only goes so far though, the URLs appear in many more places, all tables need to be processed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress stores the domain of the installation in several places of the database. So you have to change them in numerous tables. In the case of working, look at the `options` table, entries `siteurl` and `homeurl`.
It is also possible to set this via `wp-config.php`:

```
// Home URL of your WordPress.
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https:/example.com' );
// URL to the WordPress root dir.
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com' );
```

Look also inside the `wp-config.php` for the domain, because it is possible to set this via constant. The `.htaccess`, if it is an Apache server, should also validate, because the Permalink rules need the domain, especially in the 'Multisite' mode.

You should also active the [debug mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG), constant `WP_DEBUG` set to true in your `wp-config.php` to get more information about your installation, your problem. It should also help to find the issue with the REST API after domain change.

If it works fine, check also the whole database for the old domain. Because WordPress stores in various tables. A change for them is possible via SQL statement or a plugin, like 'Serach Replace'. More notes for a changing of the URL are also inside the codex - https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

Comment: Yes, issue was in the wp-config and url/home route in the db file

Answer (score 0):

Did you change all strings in the WordPress database from old domain to new domain? You can use some plugins (e.g. better search replace) or wp cli. E.g. to change from old domain to new domain, you can use old string: `https://olddomain.com` and new string `https://newdomain.com`

Also, try clearing cookies and redirections cache in the browser (ctr+shift+del on Windows, cmd+shift+backspace for Mac).